# Is main.go required in a Go project?

Tags: go

Without a background in C and only "beginner" experience in Go I'm trying to work out whether `main.go` is actually required or is just a convention.

I'm looking to create a simple web API but could someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`main.go` as a file is not required.

However, a `main` package with a `func main()` is required for executables.

Your file name can be called whatever you want.

E.g

**myawesomeapp.go**

```
package main

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello World")
}
```

Running `go run myawesomeapp.go` will work as expected.

Answer (score 11):

For a web server (an executable) you need to have a `package main` with a `func main()`, but it doesn't need to be called main.go - the file name can be anything you want it to be. From the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec):

> **Program execution**
>
> A complete program is created by linking a single, unimported package
>   called the main package with all the packages it imports,
>   transitively. The main package must have package name main and declare
>   a function main that takes no arguments and returns no value.
>
> ```
> func main() { … }
> ```
>
> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then
>   invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the
>   program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to
>   complete.